# How do I run a certain bit of code for a certain period of time?

Tags: c, stm32, nucleo

I do NOT want to measure how long a bit of code takes to run, I just want to run it for x seconds.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  clock_t t_Zero, t_Final;
  double t_Diff;
  int goodAttempt = 1;

  while (1)
  {
      if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6) == GPIO_PIN_SET) {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          t_Zero = clock();
          HAL_Delay(5000);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

          while (t_Diff < 15 && goodAttempt == 1) { // 2 * frequency * t times to blink
              //i++;
              int i = 0;
              i++;
              t_Final = clock();
              t_Diff = (double)((t_Final-t_Zero)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5);
              HAL_Delay(100);   /* Insert delay 100 ms (5Hz) */
              if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5) == GPIO_PIN_SET && HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5) == GPIO_PIN_SET) {
                  goodAttempt = 2;
                  break; // else, reset
              }

          }

}
```

This just repeatedly blinks the LED forever. It's currently 4:30AM so my code isn't the best, but I've been at this for hours and I genuinely cannot find a solution.

Comment: Better to use a timer and interrupt, see [Getting Started with STM32 - Timers and Timer Interrupts](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/getting-started-with-stm32-timers-and-timer-interrupts/d08e6493cefa486fb1e79c43c0b08cc6)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on things like `clock()` existing on an STM32. You can use `HAL_GetTicks()` to get the number of milliseconds since power-on.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idiom for something like this, on an STM32, would be:

```
uint32_t start = HAL_GetTick();

while (HAL_GetTick() - start < interval_in_milliseconds)
{
    // Do the thing
}
```

Doing the calculation with a subtraction is safe even if the tick count rolls over, which happens every ~49 days for a uint32_t millisecond counter.

There's a `}` missing from your code sample, so it's not clear which bits are included in your initial `if` or not.

Comment: Ah, thank you! And yeah, the missing } was for the while (1) loop